# Application crashes on button click

Tags: java, android

Have problem that when I press button application crashes.
Crash text 
package com.leftas.vidurkioskaiciavimas;

```
 24367-24367/com.leftas.vidurkioskaiciavimas E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3704)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3699)
            ... 11 more
            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.leftas.vidurkioskaiciavimas.vidurkioskaiciuokle.buttonEventHandler(vidurkioskaiciuokle.java:85)
        ... 14 more
```

I thinked that text is null because all time crashes on
"mUserOutput.setText(""); or "mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "10");"

So I added

```
        if (mUserOutput == null)
        Log.e("output", null);
    if (mUserInput == null)
        Log.e("input", null);
```

But Nothing outputted...

So here is my main activity.

```
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuInflater;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;



public class vidurkioskaiciuokle extends Activity {
int c;
TextView mUserOutput,mUserInput;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vidurkio_skaiciuokle);

    TextView mUserOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView mUserInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    if (mUserOutput == null)
        Log.e("output", null);
    if (mUserInput == null)
        Log.e("input", null);
}
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.vidurkioskaiciuokle, menu);
    return true;
}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
            return true;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void buttonEventHandler(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "1");
            c = +1;
            break;

        case R.id.button2 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "2");
            c = +2;
            break;

        case R.id.button3 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "3");
            c = +3;
            break;

        case R.id.button4 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "4");
            c = +4;
            break;

        case R.id.button5 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "5");
            c = +5;
            break;

        case R.id.button6 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "6");
            c = +6;
            break;

        case R.id.button7 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "7");
            c = +7;
            break;

        case R.id.button8 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "8");
            c = +8;
            break;

        case R.id.button9 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "9");
            c = +9;
            break;

        case R.id.button10 :
            mUserInput.setText(mUserInput.getText() + "10");
            c = +10;
            break;

        case R.id.buttonclear :
            mUserOutput.setText("");
            mUserInput.setText("");
            c = 0;
            double average = 0;
            break;
        }
}

public void computeAverage(int [] scores)
{
    double average = 0;
    for (int c : scores) {
        average += c;
    }

    average /= scores.length;

    mUserOutput.setText(Double.toString(average));
}
```

Xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".vidurkioskaiciuokle">

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="3"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="4"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5"
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="6"
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button5"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="7"
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="8"
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button9"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button9"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="9"
    android:id="@+id/button9"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="10"
    android:id="@+id/button10"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button5"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button7" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Clear"
    android:id="@+id/buttonclear"
    android:onClick="buttonEventHandler"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2" />
```

I will be thankful if you could me help :)

If something need ask for it I will edit my question. :)
Thanks :)

 Also If something wrong please say where and how to change it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
  mUserOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
  mUserInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

You have already Declared textview's as class member. So initialize them as above.

This

```
  TextView mUserOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
  // makes mUserOutput local
```

Comment: I will accept as answered when I allowed to do it ;) Thank you very much but my average not calculating it shows only numbers.... Could you help ? In real-time

Comment: @leftas its a string you use  `+` concatenates the strings. So use `Integer.parseInt("myString")` and then do the addition operation

Comment: @leftas again to set the integer value to textview you need to use `String.valueof(intnumber)`

Comment: I writed wrong sorry. text changes only mUserInput. mUserInput Just donsen't write anything. How I need to change it ? something like that "mUserOutput.setText(Integer.parseInt(average));" ? Could you write an example of "public void computeAverage(int [] scores)"

Comment: @leftas Suppose i have two `String s1 = "10", s2= "10"` and  `int sum=0` Then `sum = Integer.parseInt(s1)+Integer.parseInt(s2)` To set sum to textview. `textview.setText(String.valueOf(sum)`. put it under a try catch block if s1 and s2 are not numbers you will get `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Okay but how now do that go to "computeAverage" ? If you see please answer ;)

Comment: @leftas just do the math on integer values and convert the average which is an int to a string and set the same to textview. What is the problem? If you have a new doubt post a new question

Answer (score 0):

findviewbyid and mUserOutput.setOnClickListener(this); required .

also implement onLCicklistener like:
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Comment: can you explain why he has to implmenents onLCicklistener as well?

Comment: why is an OnClickListener needed? It's already defined in the XML.

Comment: sorry it's my mistake.